# Проверка на наличие данных в таблице TableView (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

Как проверить, пустая ли таблица TableView (JavaFX)? Мне нужно проверить, пустая ли таблица для выполнения условия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант

```
// предположим, что она чем-то проинициализирована 
tableView = ...;
if(tableView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
    // таблица пустая
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все робит)

Comment: не забудьте принять ответ.